# How to memorize key value elements updating also the reversing dictionary in Python language?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to modify my dictionary `d={}` updating values every time I add a new key in both direction of key-value. 
The final dictionary is:

```
d={0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 3], 3: [0, 1, 2], 4: [3, 2, 1, 0], 5: [3, 2, 1, 0], 6: [3, 2, 1, 0]}
```

But I'd like this other one:

```
d={0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 4: [3, 2, 1, 0], 5: [3, 2, 1, 0], 6: [3, 2, 1, 0]}
```

My code is :

```
d={}
s = [(3, 0.25), (2, 0.25), (1, 0.25), (0, 0.25)]
for i in range(0, 4):
    n = []
    for j in range(0, 4):
        if i != j:
           n.append(j)
           d[i] = n
print d
```

Here `d` is printed in the right way:

```
d={0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 3], 3: [0, 1, 2]}
```

Then, I add also that:

```
for i in range(4, 7):
    n = []
    for j in range(0, 4):
        k = s[j][0]
        n.append(k)
        d[i] = n
print d
```

And this last part of the code gives me the 'error' I had explained before. How can I modify the code?

Comment: What do you mean by *in both direction*?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would mean that if it prints `6:[3,2,1,0]` I'd like that `0:[1,2,3]` is updating in `0:[1,2,3,6]`, for example, and the same for all the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the right implementation:

```
for i in range(4, 7):
n = []
   for j in range(0, 4):
       k = s[j][0]
       n.append(k)
       d[i] = n
   # adding this for-loop it works
   for k in n:
       d[k].append(i)

print d
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to write a function which:

1. inserts the key - value ("list-of-keys" list) pair for you,
2. updates values (lists) assigned to keys in the "list-of-keys".